# googleapis is not displaying map randomly some times

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

We are using API for static maps. Some times map is not displayed with the correct information, Instead it displays a crossed image [image: crossed image]. This is happening randomly for few seconds.

Ex1: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=51.4666667,-116.5833333&zoom=11&size=380%20x%20380&sensor=false&markers=51.4666667,-116.5833333

Ex2: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=51.4355096,-0.405238800000006&zoom=13&size=380%20x%20380&sensor=false&markers=51.4355096,-0.405238800000006

Thanks,
Kris

Comment: Are you exceeding the quota or rate limits for the service?  Are you using and displaying the images in accordance with the terms of use?

Comment: Yes, displaying images in accordance with the terms of use; As images are served 95% of the time. How can we check Quota / Rate limits ?

Answer (score 0):

Most websites and applications may use the Google Static Maps API free of charge. However, if you consistently generate a high amount of traffic, usage limits apply and you will need to pay for extra usage. If your site or application generates 25,000 Static Maps image requests or more each day, for more than 90 consecutive days, Google will attempt to get in touch with you to talk about payment. Don't worry, if you go over the limits, Google won't immediately shut off your API access or display error messages on your site.

It is recommended that you sign up for an API key, so that you can track your usage via the Google APIs Console. Please note also that the following additional limits apply to applications that don't use an API key: 1,000 Static Maps image requests per IP address per 24 hour period, and 50 Static Maps image requests per IP address per minute.

Comment: Hi Verma,  Thanks for sharing details. I confirm, Our site usage is within the limits. Static image is served correctly if we refresh after 5 seconds of the problem occurrence.